# How to turn off active state on listview item while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I use iscroll 5 and jquery mobile 1.4.5 for cordoba android app. When I am scrolling page the i have tapped at first on start change state as it is clicked. I dont need it to be clicked if I am scrolling. I need it to change state to active only if I have tapped on it without scrolling.

How can I prevent li button item to change state, I have tried some code I found on stackoverflow but with no success.

```
$(document).on('tap', function(e) {
        $('#lista li').removeClass($.mobile.activeBtnClass);
    });
```

I tried this too, but is deprecated

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.activeBtnClass = 'unused';
});
```

Comment: it's a CSS issue. Linked list item (button) changes its' background color on `:hover`. The only way to ignore hover is adding `pointer-events:none;`, but this will ignore mouse/touch events. Or override _hover_ e.g. `.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn:hover,
html .ui-bar-a .ui-btn:hover,
html .ui-body-a .ui-btn:hover,
html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn:hover,
html head + body .ui-btn.ui-btn-a:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}`

Comment: css will fix problem only visualy, jquery mobile will still try to detect clicking and it affects smoothnes of scrolling. I need to stop javascript from detecting click while scrolling.

Comment: its an issue. Use the css to turn the normal behaviours off, and use a click function to change the state. eg the css (.activeLI {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) !important;
} ) --- the Jquery ($(document).on("click", "#thelist li >a", function(){
$(this).addClass("activeLI");
setTimeout(function() {
$("li >a").removeClass("activeLI");
 }, 50);
});)  --add this to your iscroll settings (,click:true ) -- and check here for all options in Isrcroll -- http://iscrolljs.com/

Comment: There is some problem with jquery mobile and iscroll. When I scroll it should not detect clicking. It is working great if I use readonly list, but when it is button list it is not performing good. It is not smooth scrolling. I have removed jquery css lines which are defining button states and it is not showing change, but the javascript is still detecting it. I would like to disable click detection while scrolling over button list in listview. I think it would solve the problem. When i begin scrolling with finger it is not smooth and when I release finger it becomes smooth until it stops.